# Selecting records in table of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, vb.net-2010

I'm learning SQL Server and [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET). My problem is how to select and make a condition to specific row in the table.

Like, that I have table with two columns `name, age`, and I want to select rows where name is "XY".

After that, make a condition with an (if) statement like: if age (in the table) larger than 20.

Do some thing or each one his name "xy" print his age in a messagebox.

Comment: Look up [`WHERE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188047.aspx) clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in one query like this:

```
select * from yourtable where name = 'XY' and age > 20
```

Comment: no, i want to take the value(20) of age column
like (age column=variable)
to want to use its value

Comment: @noor:- Not sure what you are looking for. If you want to match the age of 20 then simply replace > with =

Comment: then how i can use the data of tables in vb.net
to modify a row or something else

Answer (score 0):

Noor, Rahul was exactly correct in what was recommended.  It sounds like you have little experience with how to get data from a SQL query into a useable form so you can test and manipulate or analyze data.  For technology, look at ADO, and ADOX usage in VB.NET with SQL queries.  My recommendation is for you to purchase one or more good books on VB.NET, so you can fully understand how to move forward.

```
                Dim filename As String = "C:\myfile.mdb"
                Dim tablename as String = "mytable"
                Dim ConnString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data source =" & filename
                Dim cn As New OleDbConnection(ConnString)
                cn.Open()
                Dim qry As String
                Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(qry, cn)

                qry = "SELECT * FROM [" & tablename & "] WHERE name = "XY" and age > 20 ORDER by age "
                cmd.CommandText = qry
                cmd.Connection = cn
                Dim drdata As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

                Dim Cnt As Integer = 0
                Dim name(), age() as Object
                Do While drdata.Read
                    Cnt += 1
                    Redim Preserve name(Cnt)
                    Redim Preserve age(Cnt)
                    name(Cnt) = drdata.Item("name")
                    age(Cnt) = drdata.Item("age")
                Loop
                drdata.Close()

                For i As Integer = 1 to Cnt
                   If age(i) = 20 Then
                      ' do anything you want here
                   End If
                Next i
```